# eclipse android main menu with button to start new activity(ies)

Tags: android, eclipse, button

i want to have a main menu with buttons which  each will go to their own tab when clicked.Please correct the code i ve made, below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
public void produkdanpromobutton(View view){
    Intent Intentprodukpromo = new Intent(this , Produkpromotest.class);
    startActivity(Intentprodukpromo);
    }
public void simulasilist(View view){
    Intent Intentsimulasilist = new Intent(this , Simulasilistcode.class);
    startActivity(Intentsimulasilist);
    }
public void aboutus(View view){
    Intent Intentaboutus = new Intent(this , Aboutuscode.class);
    startActivity(Intentaboutus);
    }}
```

i've add the activities on manifest, and xml layout but
its not working, when i try it on eclipse simulator(android 5554 emulator)when i click one of those buttons the app will crashed.

Produkpromotest.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productpromotab);
}
```

Simulatorlistcode.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    }
```

Simulasilistcode.java found with wrong layout:
the right one:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simulasilisttab);
    }
```

Aboutuscode.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abouttab);
    }
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <Button
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="90sp"
            android:id="@+id/bprodukdanpromo"
            android:onClick="produkdanpromobutton"
            android:text="@string/produkpromo"
            android:textSize="12sp"         
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:id="@+id/bsimulasilist"
            android:onClick="simulasilist"
            android:text="@string/simulasilist"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
          <Button
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:id="@+id/babout"
            android:onClick="aboutus"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

there is no error, program works fine but when i click the button it will crash.i must be wrong somewhere, but i have no idea where.Please help me solve this

Thanks in advance,
George

Edit:added logcat

```
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Mainmenucode.produkdanpromobutton(Mainmenucode.java:18)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  ... 11 more
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg/com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Produkpromotest}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-10 15:08:33.255: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
```

Added AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Loadingawalawal"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mainmenucode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.MAINMENUCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mastercode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.MASTERCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Productpromotest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.PRODUCTPROMOTEST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Simulasilistcode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.SIMULASILISTCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Aboutuscode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.ABOUTUSCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Android Manifest editted:fixed Productpromotest to Produkpromotest,
the Produkpromo test now working, but the other still making a crash.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Loadingawalawal"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mainmenucode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.MAINMENUCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mastercode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.MASTERCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Produkpromotest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.PRODUKPROMOTEST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Simulasilistcode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.SIMULASILISTCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Aboutuscode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.ABOUTUSCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `when i click the button it will crash` please show logcat result

Comment: Please post the crash!

Comment: i added it, im also new with eclipse, how to get all logs in logcat at once(i had to save it 1 by 1 and combine the sentences).Some logs are missing,like that ....11more. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like either the activities are not added correctly to the manifest or they are spelled wrong.  Please post the manifest.

You are calling Produkpromotest.class but have it different in the manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Productpromotest"  //RIGHT HERE
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.PRODUCTPROMOTEST" /> //and here

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

try

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Produkpromotest"  //RIGHT HERE
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Produkpromotest" /> //and here

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Yes thanks,  wrong spelled Produkpromotest to Productpromotest. "k" and "ct".Thanks thxxx

Comment: its now working but only the Produkpromotest.The others still causing a crash .Its not the wrong spelling i think,any idea?

Comment: Did you name your second class "Simulasilistcode" or Simulatorlistcode.java?

Comment: no, its Simulasilistcode, i just found out my layout reference war wrong. Thanks,

Comment: yeah,all buttons working,they will start new activity when clicked.I need to be more meticulous about variables,you reminded me.Thank you